# google speech recognition triggering 'on' when I say 'crimson'

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

So I'm making python voice control for my smart lights.
But when I say 'crimson' it triggers 'on' and 'crimson' at the same time because the word 'crimson' contains 'on' at the end.
I really don't want to change the name to something else.

elif ('light' in query) or ('lights' in query):  # Home automation

```
            if 'on' in query:
                control_lights("light on")
                speak("okay, turning on light")

            if 'off' in query:
                control_lights("light off")
                speak("okay, turning off light")

            if 'crimson' in query:
                control_lights("light crimson")
                speak("okay, turning light to crimson")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of your if statements and use some elif statements so that once the word `crimson` is identified, the code will ignore the word `on`:

```
        if 'crimson' in query:
            control_lights("light crimson")
            speak("okay, turning light to crimson")

        elif 'on' in query:
            control_lights("light on")
            speak("okay, turning on light")

        if 'off' in query:
            control_lights("light off")
            speak("okay, turning off light")
```

Btw I think that your project is super cool :) I kind of want to do the same now lol

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a switch case so that it only executes 1 rather than cycling through all of your IFs?

If your voice recognition recognizes "light crimson" as "light on" and triggers that case in the switch statement, you have no choice but to change either "light on" or "light crimson" as commands, since "light crimson" = "light on" as far as the recognition can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your commands are being translated to text before execution, in that case the first `if` is satisfied because '*on*' is indeed in 'crims*on*'. So changing 'on' into some different word might fix your problem. Alternatively you can just switch the order of your `if` statments so that if you say 'crimson' it will be recognized before 'on'. 
Secondly, I would change the second and third `if`s to `elif` to avoid multiple entries to conditions in general, so once a command has been chosen, no other command will be chosen as well.